# Oracle SQL rank query

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I would like help with one of my queries.

**Here's the requirement:-**

I have to report the records whose difference between current review date and last review date is between than 365 days and more than 455 days. However, the catch here is that my customer table has just one column for the annual review date. So I have to check the historical table to find the current annual review date which in the below example is 30/04/2019 and the last review date is 30/04/2018.
How do I get just 1 line item for each record?

Below is how my table looks like, RNK column is a calculated column to determine the rank for each record, rest columns are from the table. Please help! I use Oracle 12c.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post tables as images. Use `CREATE TABLE` statements to show their structure and `INSERT INTO` statements to show sample data. Also post expected results according to the sample data, preferably in a tabular text format. Please also include the query you already have, again as plain text, not as an image. And it is of little use, if you obfuscate the IDs, as they seem vital to build the groups. If you have sensitive data you can't or don't want to post, create a set of mockup data to illustrate the problem. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: And how is the current review date defined? Is that always 2018-04-30 fix?

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `row_number()` analytical function for your `rnk` column as in the following *select* statement :

```
select row_number() over (partition by annual_review_date order by update_date) as rnk,
       t.*
  from tab t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.id, max(annual_review_dt) as latest_ard,
       min(annual_review_dt) as prev_ard
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by id order by annual_review_dt) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum in (1, 2);
```

Comment: I was initially using SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT RANK ()
                 OVER (PARTITION BY a.id, a.annuaL_review_dt
                       ORDER BY update_dt DESC, annual_review_dt)
                    AS rnk,
                 a.*
            FROM t a
           WHERE     a.annuaL_review_dt IS NOT NULL
                 AND a.stat_ind = 1